# How to introduce someone

Tags: expressions, conversation

If I have to introduce someone in a meeting what should I say?

> I would like to introduce X who has joined us from Y company.
>   I like to introduce X who is joining us from Y company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I would like to introduce" is the polite way of phrasing "I introduce", which is what you want to do here.

"I like to introduce" says that you personally enjoy the act of introducing, which is not what you are after at all.

Quite independently of that, you should pick whether you say "has joined", "is joining", "joins", "joined", "will join" or whatever according to the normal rules of tenses.  There's nothing unusual about the subordinate clause here; "has joined" tells us that X has already completed his move, "is joining" tells us that it is still being sorted out as we speak, and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure you can really classify the *would like to* component as just an extra veneer of politeness. It's pretty much the standard format - shortened to *I'd like to* in some less formal contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: exactly.  _In this context_ it softens and makes polite a blunt statement rather than carrying its literal meaning.  There are variations of the literal phrase "I would like to..." that do the same thing more or less formally: "It would give me great pleasure to..." for example.

Comment: Native English speakers would not say "I introduce X". We just don't use the present simple tense very often where the similar tense would be used in other languages.

Comment: You can leave out the *would* in @Rhodri's suggestion: "It gives me great pleasure to introduce ..." but not in "I would like to introduce ..."

Answer (score 1):

You could use any of the following:

> I would like to introduce X, who has joined us from ...
>
> I would like to introduce X, who joined us from ...
>
> I would like to introduce X, who is joining us from ...
>
> I would like to introduce X, who joins us from ...

Typically you would use "is joining" or "joins" if the hiring has been accomplished recently or will be completed in the immediate future.

Comment: The last example is incorrect.

Comment: @victoriah: Typo. Thanks for the heads up. Edited.

Comment: A minor point, I'm sure, but if I were a manager making the introduction I'd use (3) above if at all possible (i.e. - X has either *not yet* started, or only *very* recently). I just feel that gives a bit more 'immediacy', which might encourage the existing staff to enter into the spirit of welcoming the newcomer, as if their meeting X is part of the ongoing process of him joining.

Comment: "Who joins us from..." doesn't necessarily imply that X has left company Y. This phrasing is often used for conference calls, and is shorthand for "X is here as the representative of company Y."

Answer (score 0):

Its all a matter of tense

> I would like to introduce X who has
>   joined us from x company

Would be the introduction on his first day as he has already joined the company.

> I would like to introduce x who is joining
>   us from x company

Would be for introducing him after the interview and his acceptance but before he starts working for you.

That said, both would be understood perfectly well and I doubt anyone would be pedantic enough to call you on it.

Comment: Thanks..But why I have to use 'would'..Can I say I like to introduce

Comment: @anon - My mistake, would is required. `I like to introduce`, means you enjoy introducing in the same way as `I like to play golf`. This is not the meaning you're going for here!

Comment: @anon - To make that sound less formal you could use the contraction of `I would` `I'd`

Comment: No, you actually do need to say "would". That was explained here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19961/how-to-introduce-someone/19964#19964 That response describes why you must use "would". To say "I like to introduce..." is equivalent to saying "I like to {eat, talk, swim, sleep, code}". It is a way of referring to your personal preferences. In fact, the correct way, strictly speaking, would be to say "I introduce..." but that is too formal and more of an announcement. As the first answer said, the grammatically correct, and socially appropriate phrase is "I would like..."